# how to translate this slogan '向前一小步，文明一大步' and the like in almost every public toilet in China

Tags: translation, phrase, culture, mainland-china

the other one is '靠近方便, 贴近文明', both of which have different versions of English translations, most of them, though, suck. they go like:

One small step forward
One giant leap toward civilization

A small step for man, 
A giant leap for mankind

Near the civilization
Near the wall

close to civilization, 
Near to convenience

[image]

Are there any ones you guys find suitable and making sense to a western people?

Answer (score 3):

The quote from your title:

> '向前一小步，文明一大步。'

which literally translated to: `"One small step forward, (is a) big step for civilization"`

Is kind of a paraphrase of Neil Armstrong's `"One small step for a man, one giant leap for mankind"` which translates, according to Wikiquote, to:

> '这是我个人的一小步，却是全人类的一大步。'

However, as mentioned above, this is a euphemistic way of asking people to get closer to the urinals in order to keep the floor dry and clean.

Answer (score 2):

向前一小步， 文明一大步。
靠近方便, 贴近文明。

What they both want to say is: Please pee in the urinal, not on the floor.

They just say it in a very discreet Chinese way.